# Microsoft Teams REST APIs for getting channel threads

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We're interested in getting a list of conversation threads for each individual channel via Graph's REST APIs.

We have looked at the [current offerings](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/channel) in terms of endpoints, and those seem to not be there.

Something like `GET /groups/{id}/team/channels/{id}/chatthreads` or `GET /groups/{id}/channels/{id}/chatthreads` doesn't work, for example.

In addition, there are no apparent ways of replying to a thread, getting the user's personal message threads (one to one, rather than Channel specific message threads).

Any suggestions on how this data can be gathered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs to get channel messages was announced in [Build 2018](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-teams-developer-platform-enhancements-announced-for-build-2018) recently. Once those are available in Beta endpoint, you could start using them.